# How do you uninstall Orange Data Mining on Windows 11?

Tags: orange

How do you completely uninstall Orange Data Mining on Windows 11?

It is necessary to do a reinstall, and I wish to clean-out existing installations first.

What are the steps for uninstall of the standalone version, as well as the portable version.

Comment: For the portable version you shouldn't really need to uninstall anything, you can just delete the folder and its files. For the standalone version I would expect it to show up in the defaults Windows list from which you can uninstall programs.

Comment: Thank you Oxbowerce!  That is what one would expect but I have an installation on Windows 11 that does not show up in Add or Remove programs.  It was originally installed as part of Anaconda, however Anaconda was uninstalled and Orange remains.  There are even registry keys showing it in C:\Program Files\Orange, that directory does not exist in file explorer. I don't recall installing the portable version, but if I did, I don't recall where it was installed to, and no amount of searching is showing were it lives.